# @typescript-eslint/naming-convention break linting

Tags: typescript, eslint

So I would like to allow `_` on function parameters *IF* they are not used.

I edited my eslint rule :

`"@typescript-eslint/naming-convention"`

with

````
          {
            "selector": "parameter",
            "modifiers": ["unused"],
            "trailingUnderscore": "require"
          },
    ```

Following the guide 


https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/blob/main/packages/eslint-plugin/docs/rules/naming-convention.md#individual-selectors

This sould work, but I get the following error :
````

```
    Value {"selector":"parameter","modifiers":["unused"],"trailingUnderscore":"require"} should have required property 'format'.
    Value {"selector":"parameter","modifiers":["unused"],"trailingUnderscore":"require"} should match exactly one schema in oneOf.
```

Answer (score 0):

You must include the format property for the rule as an array or null value, such as:

```
{
    "format": null,
    "selector": "parameter",
    "modifiers": ["unused"],
    "trailingUnderscore": "require"
}
```

Or:

```
{
    "format": ["PascalCase"],
    ...
}
```